# Linq Expression run func in query

Tags: c#, linq

I have simple Query:

```
var ipLookup = _unit.Repository<IpLookup>().Queryable().FirstOrDefault(i =>
    ToInteger(i.From) <= intIp && ToInteger(i.To) >= intIp);
```

And I want to run this method:

```
public static long ToInteger(string ip)
{
    var arr = ip.Split('.').ToList();
    var a = Convert.ToInt32(arr[0]);
    var b = Convert.ToInt32(arr[1]);
    var c = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
    var d = Convert.ToInt32(arr[3]);

    return Convert.ToInt64((a * Math.Pow(256, 3)) + (b * Math.Pow(256, 2)) + (c * 256) + d);
}
```

I am not sure how to write expression for this to work with linq inside of query.

Comment: Please don't use `>` at the start of each line when posting code, so it looks like a quote from somewhere. Just indent by four spaces.

Comment: You should not have problems if it Linq to Object. Is it a linq to sql or linq to ... that goes to DB?

Comment: linq to sql with lambda

Answer (score 0):

When Linq-to-sql generate query to a DB it converts expressions to sql commands. It can not convert whatever code. In your case I'll recomend wright a Scalar-Valued User-Defined function with same body at .net and sql (for same behaviour). For more details see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386973(v=vs.110).aspx)